# How to replace polyline Z value equal to Nan is PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, well-known-text, invalid-data

In some polylines stored in PostGIS, I found Z values equal to NaN.

For example:

```
LINESTRING Z (30 10 0, 10 30 nan, 40 40 nan)
```

I want to replace the 'nan' with 0 to prevent subsequent errors.

Answer (score 6):

```
-- replace Nan in the text representation of the geometry    
UPDATE line SET geom = ST_SetSRID(st_geomfromtext(replace(replace(st_astext(geom), 'nan,', '0,'), 'nan)', '0)')), ST_SRID(geom))
    WHERE id in (
        -- Detect vertices with Z = Nan
        SELECT distinct id 
        FROM (
            -- Create one line for each vertice
            SELECT line.id, st_z((st_dumppoints(line.geom)).geom) AS z
            FROM line
        ) as foo
        WHERE z = double precision 'NaN'
    );
```

Comment: +1 - this is an excellent use case for WKT string manipulation! Consistently, a faster filter would be `... WHERE ST_AsText(geom) LIKE '%NaN%'`. You *could* manipulate and cast back an `ST_AsEWKT` string to save a call to `ST_SetSRID`. Also, no need to replace `'NaN'` twice (the WKT string value will be `NaN`, not `nan`, if you were trying to catch that case).